# GetMenuItemCount returning -1

Tags: winapi

Under what conditions the Win32 call [GetMenuItemCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647978(v=vs.85).aspx) can return -1, except of providing an invalid handle to the menu?

Comment: That question isn't answerable. You've already identified the most common reason. If -1 is returned, call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong. You'd be perfectly within your rights to terminate the process if this API call failed.

Comment: Weird that the `HMENU` parameter is marked optional. How is passing a `NULL` menu handle a valid invocation of that function?

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm guessing that the `_In_opt_` annotation started its life on the implementation side of the contract. It was put there so that the compiler complains in case the implementation doesn't test for `NULL`. It was then copied over to the interface, where it doesn't semantically make sense. That's speculation, though. Maybe there is more to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you can assume is that [GetMenuItemCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647978.aspx) returns -1 on failure.

Specific reasons why this API call can fail are not documented—i.e., they are not part of the published contract. They are implementation details that can change over time, so your code cannot rely upon them.

If you need to get additional information in the event of a failure, call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) as the documentation advises.

Comment: I wanted to incorporate David's claim that, assuming you passed a valid handle, "You'd be perfectly within your rights to terminate the process if this API call failed", but I didn't want to put words in your mouth. Everything you say is completely true about the contract, but in practice, this API just doesn't fail, and you don't need to waste time writing a bunch of complex error-handling code.